# Frameset won't work in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, center, frames, frameset

I have constructed a frameset which is meant to center a webpage in the middle of the browser window.

```
<html>

    <frameset rows="100%,567px,100%" border="0">
        <frame src="blank.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="yes">

        <frameset cols="100%,1128px,100%" border="0">
            <frame src="blank.html" noresize="noresize">
            <frame src="webpage.html" noresize="noresize">
            <frame src="blank.html" noresize="noresize">
        </frameset>

        <frame src="blank.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="yes">

        <noframes>
            <body>Page requires a frame-supporting browser.</body>
        </noframes>

    </frameset>

</html>
```

Blank is an empty html document. This works brilliantly in both Firefox and IE6, but in IE8 it simply shows a white page, namely the blank.html. Why is it not showing the same as in Firefox?

EDIT: This could evidently not be solved without my code, so here it is, with doctype and html tags and a few other bits excluded. I've tried your solution, but it still doesn't center vertically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-image: url(xxxbackground.gif);
}
#divInteraction {
    position:absolute;
    width:640px;
    height:480px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 460px;
    top: 47px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#divVideo {
    position:absolute;
    width:424px;
    height:284px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 13px;
    top: 101px;
    overflow: visible;
}
#imgInteraction {
}
#iframeInteraction {
display: none;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="divInteraction">
    <iframe id="iframeInteraction" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
    <img id="imgInteraction" src="powerpoint_pic_0.jpg" />
</div>

  <div id="divVideo">

     <object id="wmvVideo" width="424" height="284" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112" standby="" type="application/x-ms-wmp" VIEWASTEXT>

        <param name="AutoSize" value="false" />
        <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="0" />
        <param name="DefaultFrame" value="x" />
        <param name="ShowControls" value="1" />
        <param name="ShowAudioControls" value="1" />
        <param name="ShowPositionControls" value="0" />
        <param name="ShowTracker" value="1" />
        <param name="ShowDisplay" value="0" />
        <param name="ShowCaptioning" value="0" />
        <param name="ShowGoToBar" value="0" />
        <param name="ControlType" value="2" />
        <param name="Autostart" value="1" />
        <param name="InvokeUrls" value="1" />
        <param name="AnimationAtStart" value="0" />
        <param name="TransparentAtStart" value="0" />
        <param name="SendStateChangeEv" value="1" />
        <param name="SendOpenChangeEv" value="1" />
        <param name="SendPlayChangeEv" value="1" />
        <param name="AllowChangeCtrlType" value="1" />
        <param name="AllowChangeDisplaySize" value="1" />
        <param name="AllowScan" value="1" />
        <param name="AutoRewind" value="1" />
        <param name="PlayCount" value="1" />
        <param name="Volume" value="0" />   
        <param name="Filename" value="http://www.example.com/example/example.wmv"/>


    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2"
    pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/download/"
    name="Player1NS"
    AutoSize="false"
    ShowStatusBar="0"
    DefaultFrame="x"
    ShowControls="1"
    ShowTracker="1"
    ShowDisplay="0"
    ShowCaptioning="0"
    ShowGoToBar="0"
    Autostart="1"
    AnimationAtStart="0"
    TransparentAtStart="0"
    PlayCount="1"
    Volume="0"
    Filename="http://www.example.com/example/example.wmv"
    ShowAudioControls="1"
    ShowPositionControls="0"     
    width="424"
    height="284">
    <br />

  </embed>    
 </object>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please let me ask you if the usage of frameset is really necessary for your website?

Comment: Well, if you could supply a way to center a div in the middle of a page through CSS it wouldn't be neccessary. But I have yet to find a method for that.

Comment: You mentioned that you are supplying the doctype in your second code block but there is no doctype in either block.

Comment: I said that I excluded the doctype and html tags. I can correct it if it was misunderstood.

Comment: IE8 is still beta. You should wait until its final version is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a frameset. The code below will center a div in the page.

The horizontal centering is done by setting the left and right margins to auto. The vertical centering is done by placing the top of the div 50% down the page, then use a negative top margin that is half the height of the div to move it up to the center.

You also need to specify the height of the `html` and `body` elements to 100%, otherwise they will only be as high as the content.

The div has `position:relative` which also takes care of your problem with absolutely positioned elements inside it. The div becomes a layer, which means that any absolutely positioned element inside it will use the top left corner of the div as zero point, not the page.

The border on the div is only to see where it is. You can remove that.

The code is tested in Firefox 3, IE 7, IE 8 beta and Opera 9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://data.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://data.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Center</title>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
.Content {
   width: 1128px; height: 567px;
   margin: -283px auto 0; position: relative; top: 50%;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Content">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
Here is the code with the contents and style pasted in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://data.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://data.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Center</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
<style type="text/css">

html { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; background-image: url(xxxbackground.gif); }
.Content { width: 1128px; height: 567px; margin: -283px auto 0; position: relative; top: 50%; }

#divInteraction {
        position:absolute;
        width:640px;
        height:480px;
        z-index:1;
        left: 460px;
        top: 47px;
        overflow: hidden;
}
#divVideo {
        position:absolute;
        width:424px;
        height:284px;
        z-index:2;
        left: 13px;
        top: 101px;
        overflow: visible;
}
#imgInteraction {
}
#iframeInteraction {
display: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Content">

<div id="divInteraction">
        <iframe id="iframeInteraction" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
        <img id="imgInteraction" src="powerpoint_pic_0.jpg" />
</div>

  <div id="divVideo">

         <object id="wmvVideo" width="424" height="284" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" 

codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112" standby="" 

type="application/x-ms-wmp" VIEWASTEXT>

                <param name="AutoSize" value="false" />
                <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="0" />
                <param name="DefaultFrame" value="x" />
                <param name="ShowControls" value="1" />
                <param name="ShowAudioControls" value="1" />
                <param name="ShowPositionControls" value="0" />
                <param name="ShowTracker" value="1" />
                <param name="ShowDisplay" value="0" />
                <param name="ShowCaptioning" value="0" />
                <param name="ShowGoToBar" value="0" />
                <param name="ControlType" value="2" />
                <param name="Autostart" value="1" />
                <param name="InvokeUrls" value="1" />
                <param name="AnimationAtStart" value="0" />
                <param name="TransparentAtStart" value="0" />
                <param name="SendStateChangeEv" value="1" />
                <param name="SendOpenChangeEv" value="1" />
                <param name="SendPlayChangeEv" value="1" />
                <param name="AllowChangeCtrlType" value="1" />
                <param name="AllowChangeDisplaySize" value="1" />
                <param name="AllowScan" value="1" />
                <param name="AutoRewind" value="1" />
                <param name="PlayCount" value="1" />
                <param name="Volume" value="0" />       
                <param name="Filename" value="http://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxx.wmv"/>


        <embed type="application/x-mplayer2"
        pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/download/"
        name="Player1NS"
        AutoSize="false"
        ShowStatusBar="0"
        DefaultFrame="x"
        ShowControls="1"
        ShowTracker="1"
        ShowDisplay="0"
        ShowCaptioning="0"
        ShowGoToBar="0"
        Autostart="1"
        AnimationAtStart="0"
        TransparentAtStart="0"
        PlayCount="1"
        Volume="0"
        Filename="http://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxx.wmv"
        ShowAudioControls="1"
        ShowPositionControls="0"         
        width="424"
        height="284">
        <br />

  </embed>    
 </object>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. The inside elements are still in their original positions, and the background image has magically disappeared (even if I put the background-image in the Content class).

Comment: I pasted your content and styles in the page (posted above), and it works just fine. The background image is there, and the div's are positioned inside the Content div.

Comment: The background image must be centered too(forgot to say that... seems to be something I do all the time), not just placed in the body.

Comment: Just change background-image to background, and add repeat (repeat-x/repeat-y/no-repeat) and horizontal and vertical positioning (ex. center center) after the url().

Comment: The image is now centered, but I noticed now that the inside divs are shifted to far right and down. There are black "holes" on the background image that the two divs must fit in, and they are off by the same distance. Tried setting them to position:relative, but that messed up the video div...

Comment: Check if the position coordinates are correct. You probably had a margin on the body before, so the coordinates may be adjusted for that.

Answer (score 3):

Oh my!

You can achieve the exact same result with the following css in your webpage.html file:

```
body {
  width: 1128px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 567px;
}
```

Please not that setting the margin-top to 567 pixel will only center your content for a specific screen resolution.

if IE is touchy on the body tag, you can embed the whole content of the body with a div:

```
    <body>
      <div id="content" >
         <-- YOUR CONTENT -->
      </div>
    <body>
```

Then use the following css:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div#content {
  width: 1128px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 567px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

And now apply all the css rules you had for the body to div#content.

EDIT: So I see the html code now.

You should try position:relative instead of absolute for your divs and see what happens with the last "solution" I submitted.

Also, remove all your previous margin settings in your body css rule and move the background image to the div#content rule.

... and let me know :P

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Might it have something to do with the fact that the page contains display:absolute elements and that it has a background image?

Comment: No, it's probably the weird handling of body by IE.
I'll edit my answer with something that should solve the issue.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think that the content div believes that it is empty, because all of the other divs inside it are set to display:absolute. And I just realize that no amount of css on the body or content div would work, since all inside divs are absolute anyway :(

Comment: Meh, meant position:absolute.

Comment: Yes, I tried just that. The entire content div was just shifted down by 567px, and the video div was in the completely wrong place.